# How can i make my count increment from zero respectively

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

I am having a condition as follows

```
if (fedId == ftax)
{
  index = 0;
  string strEntryDets = string.Empty;
  strEntryDets = EntryDetail().ToString();
  sbBatchHeaderFile.AppendLine(strEntryDets);
}
```

When this statement is true i should increment the index value starting from zero can any one give me an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is your iteration logic and when you are using all this stuff thats why I'm giving this suggestion.

Add this class to your application:

```
  public class IndexHolder
    {
        private static int m_Index = -1;
        public static int GetNext()
        {
            return m_Index++;
        }
        public static void Reset()
        {
            m_Index = -1;
        }
    }
```

In your code use as this :

```
index = IndexHolder.GetNext();
```

Answer (score 2):

Set it to zero outside the if block. 
Also, what's the point of setting strEntryDets to an emptry string if you're just going to set it again on the very next line?  In fact, you can just avoid setting that variable altogether.

```
index = 0;

if (fedId == ftax)
{
  index++;
  sbBatchHeaderFile.AppendLine(EntryDetail().ToString());
}
```

If you need to use index (starting at zero) and THEN increment it, you can do this:

```
if (fedId == ftax) 
{
  foo(index++);
}
```

This will pass in 0 and then increment it to 1.

Comment: But this will increment index to 1 but i need the count from zero

Comment: Then just move the index++ to the end of the code block - after the appendline.

Comment: Set `index = -1` outside the block

Comment: If equals then i have to start the count from 0 and then 1,2 respectively

Comment: Set starting position to -1 then... Didn't get question - where is problem?

Comment: When are you incrementing??  You just have a single if block.